# Change search icon to clear input as user types?

Tags: search, input-fields, search-suggestion

We use the search icon more as visual indicator than actionable item. When the user types it changes to clear input icon. Has anyone seen this as a pattern before? I feel it does it's job.

[image]

Comment: yes, it's relatively common. we did it for one website a few months ago, and you can see something more or less similar on Google (it just doesn't toggle icons, but the principle is the same. Not sure what teh question is though

Comment: @Devin Thank you I was wondering was this a pattern that anyone has seen before.

Answer (score 1):

It is interesting that the StackExchange search bar at the top doesn't implement a clear input text feature.

There are many reasons why you might want to do this, although usually it seems to make sense to keep the search and clear features visible at all times to create less confusion for new users. I think that using the search icon only as a visual indicator can lead to some user confusion.

What you are doing is certainly not something new, and has been used in applications where it makes sense because of the typical type of input or corrections that people tend to make.